# Obtaining context for SQLiteOpenHelper constructor

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to delete a record from an SQLite DB and a recyclerview in android after the user clicks an image button on one of the list items.

The item is deleting from the recyclerview but I don't understand how to delete it from the DB.

I know an instance of my DatabaseHelper class must be created to call my remove method, but I am unsure of what to pass as a parameter as the context as I'm calling this inside of my recyclerview adapter onBindViewHolder method.

I have tried using 'this', and passing a variable of type Context, both of which are null. I'm unsure how to proceed.

Also, should I change the location of where I create the DatabaseHelper? I feel like having to create a new instance on every click may be unnecessary.

Any help is appreciated.

The following is from the RecyclerViewAdapter class.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    final Contact contact = contactsList.get(position);
    viewHolder.contactName.setText(contact.getFullName());
    viewHolder.contactInitials.setText(contact.getInitials());

    viewHolder.removeItemImgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(); //Unsure what to pass in as the context here
            databaseHelper.removeContact(contactsList.get(position).getEmailAddress());
            contactsList.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, contactsList.size());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Use `view.getContext()`. If it was clicked, then it has a Context :) And check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008914/how-to-use-or-instantiate-sqlite-database-helper-class-instance-inside-a-custom)

Comment: That worked dude, appreciate the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use or instantiate Sqlite Database Helper class instance inside a custom dapter class in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008914/how-to-use-or-instantiate-sqlite-database-helper-class-instance-inside-a-custom)